# Beginner to web design, need to know why style isn't being invoked

Tags: html, css

So I have been following the courses on CodeAcademy (lame I know but it's a step) and now feel comfortable writing my own HTML/CSS. However, I found when I started doing so (I have been using sublimetext 3) and I open my html file, the css is not applied. I tried again using some code from codeacademy that worked and again Chrome just displayed the plain html. Here is my code from files

template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>Strut Your Stuff!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>I'm about to become a lovely shade of teal.</p>
        <p>Me, too!</p>
        <p>I think I'll do the same.</p>
        <div>
            <p>We're going to become a truly striking scarlet!</p>
            <p>I was thinking more vermillion.</p>
            <p>No, crimson!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and stylesheet.css

```
p{
    color:#00E5EE;
}
div p{
    color:#CC0000;
}
*{
    border:1px dashed #3A5FCD;
}
```

Both files are located in the same directory. If you guys could share any insight as to what is happening it would help me out a lot. Thanks in advance.

Update: I discovered that simply reloading a page would not work. I needed to open a new tab and type the directory back in.

Comment: use firebug/inspect element to see whether there are any errors in loading your resources.

Comment: Your code works as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jrk45/), so I gess it's a loading problem. Do you need that trailing `/` in your link element?

Comment: Maybe set @charset "UTF-8"; in the top of css file and <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> to the file

Comment: this works locally for me in chrome.  In addition to the above comments - double check your filenames - upper/lower case.

Comment: I agree with dc5, check the case, if your server is running linux this is very important.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was reloading the page simply wouldn't work. I would create the stylesheet, then hit the reload button. What I needed to do was open a new tab and paste the directory of the html file again. Thank you for all insights

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner, you need to learn that the "developer tools" are your best friend when debugging issues like this.

If you press the F12 key in Chrome, this will open the Developer Tools, which are useful in so many ways for debugging web issues.

If you click the "Network" tab of the developer tools, and refresh your screen, you can see all the requests your page is making, and what is returned.  From the description of your problem - it is very likely that you will see "404" under the status for the .css file - meaning that it couldn't be found, most likely because you have the filename wrong, or the wrong path.

If you click on the elements tab, you can see a hierarchical view of the elements on the page.  You can select one of them, and see the styles applied to it on the right.  This will let you see which (if any) css rules are applied to a given element.

Answer (score -1):

Try embedding your stylesheet into your html file on the head section

```
<style TYPE="text/css">
<!--
p{
    color:#00E5EE;
}
div p{
    color:#CC0000;
}
*{
    border:1px dashed #3A5FCD;
}
-->
</style>
```

If this works (which will work... ) then you will need to check the path of both your html and css files.
Run your html on a browser and check the url. Then replace the template.html with stylesheet.css and see if your stylesheet shows up. If it doesn't that would be a filepath problem. 
Let us know how this went